# Using ImageMagick, how can I resize an image to have minimum height or width, which ever is reached first

Tags: image, imagemagick, image-manipulation

https://imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/

I do not quite understand how I can resize images to have either a minimum of for example 1000px height OR 1000px width, whichever is reached first, but at the same time do not change images that are a smaller size to begin with as well as keeping the aspect ratio and not filling or cropping the image.

**Some examples of what I am trying to achieve:**

```
2000 x 1500 -> 1500 x 1000 (reduced so width fits)
1500 x 2000 -> 1000 x 1500 (reduced so height fits)
2000 x 2000 -> 1000 x 1000 (reduced so both fit)
1100 x 1000 -> 1100 x 1000 (do not change since one measure already fits)
1000 x 1100 -> 1000 x 1100 (do not change since one measure already fits)
1000 x  900 -> 1000 x  900 (do not change since one measure already fits)
 900 x 1000 ->  900 x 1000 (do not change since one measure already fits)
 600 x  500 ->  600 x  500 (do not change since image is smaller)
```

**What I have tried:**
Fill Area Flag ('^' flag) + Only Shrink Larger Images ('>' flag)

Using an example image of 1842 x 1596

```
magick in.png -resize 1000x1000^> out.png
```

But this results in an image that is 1000 x 866 while the result I am looking for would be 1154 x 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the comment before i arrived at

```
magick.exe in.png -resize "%[fx:min(w,h)<=1000 ? w : ( w>h ? (w/h*1000) : 1000) ]" out.png
```

Give it a shot and tell me if it works for all your usecases

Answer (score 0):

I have not fully tested this, but try the following in Imagemagick 7 (only).

```
magick in.png -resize "%[fx:max(w,h)>1000?1000:max(w,h)]" out.png
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am on ImageMagick 7.1.0-41 and running this on my example png with 1842 x 1596 also resulted in a 1000 x 866 image. When you said 7 only, did you mean 7.0 only, or should it work with my version as well?

Comment: It should work on any **ImageMagick** v7.x.x but not v6.x.x.

Comment: @MarkSetchell does it produce the correct results for you? I reinstalled ImageMagick and it still only gives me a 1000 x 866 picture. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is not 1000x866 what you want. It should reduce preserving aspect ratio.

Comment: @fmw42 No, 1154x1000 is what i wanted (no side smaller than 1000px). The other answer does this, but thank you as well for trying to help!

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your requirements.